# Как изменить атрибут title на другое значение

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте есть ссылки с всплывающими подсказками, оформленные через атрибут `title`

Необходимо атрибут `title` заменить на атрибут `data-yjsg-tip` и добавить класс "yjsg-tip-top" самой ссылке.

Как сейчас:

```
<a href="http://site.ru" title="Текст подсказки">Текст ссылки</a>
```

Как нужно:

```
<a href="http://site.ru" class="yjsg-tip-top" data-yjsg-tip="Текст подсказки">Текст ссылки</a>
```

Если с добавление класса ссылке более-менее понятно (через `addClass`), то замена атрибута никак не получается, замена (`replace`) не срабатывает, а если удалить атрибут (`removeAttr`) и попытаться создать новый, то значения, уже присутствующие у атрибута `title`, теряются.

Это вообще возможно сделать? Если да, то как решение этой задачи оформить в виде скрипта?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$('a[title]').each(function() {
  if (this.title) {
    $(this).addClass('yjsg-tip-top').attr('data-yjsg-tip', this.title);
    $(this).removeAttr('title'); // если нужно удалить title
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://site.ru" title="Текст подсказки">Ссылка с title</a><br />
<a href="http://site.ru" title="">Ссылка с пустым title</a><br />
<a href="http://site.ru">Ссылка без title</a>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает, то что нужно! и да сам атрибут title после изъятия из него значения за ненадобностью удаляем, как и предусмотрено у вас в ответе!

Comment: Дальше-больше, а подскажите еще пожалуйста: как сделать чтобы скрипт не срабатывал если значение title пустое или отсутствует? А то сейчас красиво оформленные подсказки всплывают даже там, где title отсутствует или не прописан т.е. пустые )

Comment: @Slava обновил ответ

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо, все работает, и последнее, если я в скрипте через запятую перечислю список div в которых должно срабатывать правило, насколько это правильно? Или нужно для каждого div отдельно правило прописывать (дублировать код). Что меньше создает нагрузку?

Comment: @Slava можете просто писать $('.selector, .selector1, #selector2')

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример, возможно это подойдет

```js
$("a").attr("data-yjsg-tip", "Текст подсказки");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Comment: К сожалению нет, этот вариант не подходит по причине того, что подсказки в title уже присутствуют.. вот мне и нужно title заменить на data-yjsg-tip  Этот вариант бы подошел, если бы взять значение атрибута title (текст подсказки), и добавить это значение к новому/создаваемому атрибуту data-yjsg-tip,  а после этого сам атрибут title (вместе со значением) удалить.. Но как это реализовать не хватает знаний..